AR flutter asset not rendering? Unable to render asset
So I have a problem with my asset. It can't load when it should appear when I tapped the screen.
enter image description here
here is my code
enter image description here
pubsec.yaml
enter image description here
with the correct path
enter image description here
I don't know why it can't load. it is related to this?
enter image description here
I tried to clear cache flutter but it didnt work. and i also doubled check the path and its correct. what should i do?
